# Two curves filling a surface

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Let $S$ be a closed surface of genus $g \geq 2$. Do there exist two simple closed curves filling $S$?

**Definitions**:

Two closed curves $\alpha$, $\beta$ *fill $S$* if they have minimal intersection  and $S \setminus (\alpha \cup \beta)$ is a union of topological disks.

$\DeclareMathOperator\card{card}$Two closed curves $\alpha$, $\beta$ *have minimal intersection* if $\card(\alpha \cap \beta) \leq \card(\alpha' \cap \beta')$ for all $\alpha'$ in the homotopy class of $\alpha$ and for all $\beta'$ in the homotopy class of $\beta$.

Comment: Yes, otherwise curve complex would have diameter at most 2, while in fact it has infinite diameter. Pick your favorite simple nontrivial loops $a$ and $b$ and your favorite pseudoanosOv homeomorphism $f$. Now, apply a high power of $f$ to $b$ and do not change $a$. The result is a filling pair of loops.  

Comment: Sorry:  S(α∪β) in  the question is a typo for S∖(α∪β), right?

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

Here is a quick but nonelementary proof; however, if you are interested in geometry and topology of surfaces, or Teichmuller theory, you should learn about curve complex in any case, this is a very powerful tool for studying mapping class groups, etc.

Let $X=C(S)$ be the curve complex of the surface $S$, see e.g. 
[Schleimer's notes here](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~saulsch/Maths/notes.pdf). 
Vertices of $X$ are isotopy classes of simple nontrivial loops on $S$; two vertices are connected by an edge iff the loops can be made disjoint. Equip $X$ with the path-metric where every edge has unit length. If $\alpha, \beta$ are vertices of $X$ so that the pair $(\alpha, \beta)$ does not fill in the surface $S$, then the distance between $\alpha, \beta$ in $X$ is at most $2$, since you can find a nontrivial loop disjoint from both $\alpha$ and $\beta$. On the other hand, $X$ is connected and has infinite diameter, see the same source as above. Thus, there are pairs of loops in $S$ which fill.

Answer (score 1):

A first obvious remark: if there are two curves separating the surface as required, up to a generic perturbation they have an intersection of finite cardinality. So by well-ordering, there are two such curves with intersection of minimal cardinality. In other words, the requirement that $\mathrm{card}(\alpha\cup\beta)$ be be minimal can always be ensured, if there are two not necessarily minimal separating curves.

If two surfaces  have this property, so does their connected sum (w.r.to the connected sum of the disks suitably arranged). Also, the property is certainly true for the sphere, for the torus, and for the real projective plane, by direct decomposition. Therefore the property it is true for any closed surface, since it is a connected sum of some copies of the preceding.

Comment: @Pietro: This induction (on genus) argument does not work without some extra efforts: You have to specify how you perform the connected sum relative to the curves you constructed for lower genus surfaces (say, tori). If you try to do so naively, say, by removing small disks near the double intersection points, then you may loose the "filling" condition after the connected sum (just consider the case of connected sum of two tori). 

Comment: yes, one may loose the filling condition if the connected sum is made naively; but if the disks and the small hole for the sum are "suitably arranged", I think one should obtain a decomposition into two disks for the connected sum. However, I didn't bother to go into the details.

Comment: Pietro: One could also (naively) try to take connected sum outside of the curves, but then you loose filling property as well (even worse, instead of 2 curves, you may end up with four). So, "suitably arranged" needs a real explanation. 

Comment: sure, that's all clear. I think the questioner is able to fix these details.

Comment: Prof. Majer: suppose that the surface minus the filling curves is a connected disk (it happens for the torus, for example). I can't figure out how to do the connected sum in a suitable way.

Comment: me neither, but the idea was to do the decomposition of the connected sum by two curves without bothering to the minimality of intersection (for then there is also a pair of curves with minimal intersection). 
Say, for the connected sum we use as hole on $S$ a disk that is a component of $S\setminus(\alpha\cup\beta)$, and whose boundary is made by one arc of $\alpha$ and one of $\beta$; analogously on $S'$. Gluing the boundaries of these disks so as to identify the corresponding arcs of $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ on $S'$we get 2 curves on the connected sum whose complement is a union of disks. 

Comment: Precisely, the two filling curves on the connected sum are the connected sum of α and α′, resp. β and β′. Is this description clear?

Comment: I think there are two problems:
- the arcs of \alpha and \beta that you used can be on the boundary of the same disk (not the disk you removed, I'm saying in the remaining part of the surface)
-if a pair of curves decompose the surface in a union of disks you cannot say that the corresponding pair realizing minimal intersection do the same

Comment: and also, third, it is not guaranteed that there is a disk whose boundary is made by an arc of α and one of β in S (and in S'). To create such a disk, one can perturb α and β near a crossing point, creating new small disks; in particular, with the two arcs not belonging to the closure of the same disk, as per your remark one. In any case, the aim of the construction was not a *minimal* decomposition for the connected sum (see my initial "obvious remark", so that the problem two is also not difficult).

Comment: I have to say that I suggested this hint of connected sums because it may possibly suggest some construction or computation to you (e.g., an upper bound on the cardinality of the intersection in terms of the genus of S). I hope it may be useful. That said, it seems to me that just the existence of the two filling curves follows from quick and elementary arguments. 


Comment:   I'd say: 1) an open subset of S bounded by a closed simple curve is always an Euclidean disk provided its diameter is smaller than some $\epsilon$ (e.g the Lebesgue number of a covering of S by Euclidean disks). 2) Two non-disjoint closed simple curves α and β produce connected components of S∖(α∪β) whose boundaries are closed simple curves (e.g. they can't produce an annulus). 3) There are two non-disjoint closed simple curves α and β such that all the components of S∖(α∪β) have diameter smaller than $\epsilon$, therefore they are disks. Then minimize card(α∩β) as said. 

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concrete and elementary construction. Let $\{p_j\}_{j=1}^{n}$ be the curves in an embedded pants decomposition of $S$. Let $\alpha$ be a curve so that the intersection number $i(\alpha, p_j) \geq 1$ for all $j$, and put $\alpha$ in minimal position. Let $D_{p_j}$ denote the Dehn twist around $p_j$. Define $\beta$ to be the result of Dehn twisting $\alpha$ twice around each $p_j$: that is,  $\beta = D_{p_1}^2 ... D_{p_n}^2 \alpha$.

Then $\alpha, \beta$ are a filling pair. The effect of the Dehn twists is to cut out disks which pull apart each pair of pants. The requirement that $i(\alpha, p_j) \geq 1$ ensures that each pair of pants is cut along at least two seams. After these two cuts, each pair of pants becomes a disk. Any further cuts then only cut these disks into more disks.